# I can't load any scss files from my project in react

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, sass, postcss

I don't know what happened but I was just trying to build my project and out of nowhere I couldn’t run my project anymore.

The problem is to all the files, if they trying to import 'css' file it's okay but 'scss', nop.

That is from Docker:

`2023-10-25 16:38:40  ✓ Compiled /not-found in 1372ms (2783 modules) 2023-10-25 16:38:40  ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error. 2023-10-25 16:38:58  ⨯ ./src/components/background/background.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[4]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[5]!./src/components/background/background.scss 2023-10-25 16:38:58 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop') 2023-10-25 16:38:58  2023-10-25 16:38:58 Import trace for requested module: 2023-10-25 16:38:58 ./src/components/background/background.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[4]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[5]!./src/components/background/background.scss 2023-10-25 16:38:58 ./src/components/background/background.scss 2023-10-25 16:38:58 ./src/components/background/background.tsx 2023-10-25 16:38:58 ./src/app/page.tsx`

This one from google chrome:

`./src/components/background/background.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[4]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[13].use[5]!./src/components/background/background.scss Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop')`

I got really no idea where it is coming from, if someone got an idea?

Thanks.

After building the project, I tried to run the project one more time and then I got that problem.

Project on react, on macos, using docker.

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

// Adding SASS
const path = require('path')
const nextConfig = {
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: If you can provide the webpack config along with questions then it would be great. also check if there is any syntex error in .scss file.

Comment: My bad I will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed my problem, it was my `package-lock.json` which was corrupted. I deleted that file and `node_modules` and reinstalled everything and it worked.

I got the answer from [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/47394#issuecomment-1657223047).